# Change language in a Flutter package (flutter)

Tags: flutter, package

as I wrote in the title I'd like to display this flutter package [https://pub.dev/packages/date_picker_timeline] in Italian language.
How can I do? I'm into flutter since mid 2021 so I'm not an expert.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!
Inside the package there is a file with a locale property.
Just change "en_US" to your language like "it_IT" in my case.

Thanks to all! bye!!

Answer (score 0):

So what i would try is to use the this.locale in the Constructor and change it to your local value. On the Example in the documentation they used en_US.
[Documentation locale](https://pub.dev/packages/date_picker_timeline)

Maybe a look into locale from flutter will help you.
[Internationalizing Flutter apps](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've already tried this way but I could't realise my purpose. Surely because I'm not an expert. Can you, or someone else give an example?
I've already tried this way changing it to it_IT and many others like fr_FR but nothing changed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61529343/how-to-change-language-of-show-date-picker-in-flutter Maybe this could help.